# Array to valid json PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am using the Adobe Sign API and I need to map fields from a php array to the fields in a pdf document. I have managed to do it using the following json:

```
"mergeFieldInfo": [ 

        {
            "defaultValue": company['Trading Name'],
            "fieldName": "Trading Name"
        },
        {
            "defaultValue": company['Company Website'],
            "fieldName": "Company Website"
        }
]
```

The problem is I have 3 different pdf's all with 60+ fields. Is there anyway I could create this json structure by looping through the array? So far I have split the array in to two. One holds the default values and the other the field names not sure if thats the right way to be going

Comment: Have you looked at [`json_encode()` its hidden in the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and designed to convert PHP arrays or objects into JSON Strings

Comment: I think you have converted each array element in to a JSON object with two elements and you haven't split the array in to two as you said.

Comment: @krionz not sure what you're on about

Comment: Your code shows a JSON with an array called mergeFieldInfo, and this array has two objects each object with two properties, so it doesn't match what you said: One holds the default values and the other the field names

Comment: Because that JSON is manually written and is JSON. I am on about the `company` array. Which has been split into two, one holding the values and the other the keys.

Comment: I think there is no need for two arrays, one array with the keys as the fileNames and the array values as the defaultValues, then you can loop through the fields from the PDFs and map them to the array keys to get the values.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using `json_encode`

```
foreach ($company as $key => $value){
        $arr[] =  ['defaultValue' => $value, 'fieldName' =>$key];
}
json = json_encode($arr);
```

Result:

```
{"defaultValue":"New Company","fieldName":"trade_name"},
{"defaultValue":"Website","fieldName":"website"}
```